# Swift 3.0: What is the neatest way to tackle this scenario with enums?

Tags: swift, enums, swift3

Say, I have a bunch of objects. I'd like to filter them, based on Shape or Color.

The Shape may be Square or Triangle

```
enum Shape{ case Square, Triangle }
```

The Color may be Red or Green

```
enum Color{ case Red, Green }
```

What I want is a method as follows, which accepts an array of filters, which may be Shape or Color, or both.

```
func apply(_ filters: [Filter]){
   for filter in filters{
      if it's a Shape filter, apply that
      if it's a Color filter, apply that
   }
}
```

And then I can populate an array as follows and pass it to the method above:

```
let filters = [Shape.Triangle, Color.Green, Color.Red] // get objects which are triangle, or have color red, or have color green
```

What I can't seem to figure out is what the relationship between Filter and Shape/Color should be, in order for this to work. I tried nesting them as follows, but that doesn't work:

```
enum Filter{
    enum Shape{...}
    enum Color{...}
}
```

because of the type mismatch in the following line:

```
let filters: [Filter] = [Filter.Shape.Square, Filter.Color.Green, Filter.Color.Red]
```

Ideas, anyone? What's a good way to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way handling your case is using protocol.

With declaring `Filter` as a protocol, and make your `Shape` and `Color` conform to it:

```
protocol Filter {}
extension Shape: Filter {}
extension Color: Filter {}
```

You can write something like this:

```
let filters: [Filter] = [Shape.Square, Color.Green, Color.Red]

func apply(_ filters: [Filter]){
    for filter in filters{
        if filter is Shape {/* apply that */}
        if filter is Color {/* apply that */}
    }
}
```

You can define some methods for `Filter` protocol, but that depends on your actual use case.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative: use a common enum for the filters, where each case of the enum holds an associated value which is a subfilter type (shape, color, and so on)

```
enum Shape { 
    case square, triangle, circle
}

enum Color { 
    case red, green, blue
}

enum Filter {
    case shape(Shape)
    case color(Color)
}
```

Example setup:

```
struct Object {
    let id: Int
    let shape: Shape
    let color: Color
    init(_ id: Int, _ shape: Shape, _ color: Color) {
        self.id = id
        self.shape = shape
        self.color = color
    }
}

let bunchOfObjects = [
    Object(1, .square,   .red),     Object(2, .square,   .blue),
    Object(3, .square,   .green),   Object(3, .square,   .red),
    Object(5, .triangle, .green),   Object(4, .triangle, .blue),
    Object(7, .circle,   .red),     Object(5, .circle,   .green),
    ]
```

Example filtering for `square` shapes with color `red` (AND `&&` conditions)

```
let filters: [Filter] = [.shape(.square), .color(.red)]

let filteredObjects = bunchOfObjects.filter {
    obj in
    filters.reduce(true) {
        switch($1) {
            case .shape(let shape): return $0 && obj.shape == shape
            case .color(let color): return $0 && obj.color == color
        }
    }
}

filteredObjects.forEach { print($0.id, $0.shape, $0.color) }
/* 1 square red
   3 square red */
```

Or, filtering using OR `||` conditions, for objects that fulfil at least one of the conditions in the `filters` array (is a square or has color red; or both).

```
let filters: [Filter] = [.shape(.square), .color(.red)]

let filteredObjects = bunchOfObjects.filter {
    obj in
    filters.reduce(false) {
        switch($1) {
            case .shape(let shape): return $0 || obj.shape == shape
            case .color(let color): return $0 || obj.color == color
        }
    }
}

filteredObjects.forEach { print($0.id, $0.shape, $0.color) }
/* 1 square red
   2 square blue
   3 square green
   3 square red
   7 circle red */
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an `OptionSet` to accomplish this, details can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optionset

In your case a basic implementation would look like this:

```
struct Filters: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let shapeSquare    = Filters(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let shapeTriangle  = Filters(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let colourRed   = Filters(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let colourGreen   = Filters(rawValue: 1 << 3)
}

let filters: Filters = [Filters.shapeSquare, Filters.colourRed]
```

An option set is essentially a way of having multiple enum cases apply at the same time, without using an array. A few examples are `UIAnimationOptions` and `UIUserNotificationSettings`.

I suggest reading into it yourself at the link above.

Comment: you can simplify to `let filters: Filters = [.shapeSquare, .colourRed]`

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Shape {
    case square, triangle, circle
}

enum Color {
    case red, green, blue
}

struct Thing {
    var color = .red
    var shape = .square
}

let it = Thing()

let filters = [
    { return $0.color == .red },
    { return $0.shape == .square }
]
let isOk = filters.map { $0(it) }.reduce(true, combine: { $0 && $1 })
```